# Git in visual studio : Cannot create local repository outside project directory

Tags: git, visual-studio

Is it possible to have the local repo of a given project in another directory than the project directory ?

Comment: What do you expect to go into the repository if not the project?

Comment: Cannot really get the point. Not criticizing, but questioning.
I'm a newbie on git and being confused with [this tuto](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/02/06/set-up-connect-and-publish-using-visual-studio-with-git.aspx#publish). I'm more use to svn where the repo is centralized. Though outside the project on a disctinct server. 
Do you mean that git is a sort of sync tool that absolutely have to be in the same directory than the project no matter what ? Or is there an option to have it outside the directory ?

Comment: *I'm more use to svn where the repo is centralized* Yeah well Git is decentralised so when you're dealing with Git, check-in your Subversion knowledge at the door.

Comment: svn has its .svn dirs, git has its .git dir. If you want a second repo to push your work to that's easy, clone it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that. This [link](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Git-Basics#Snapshots,-Not-Differences) seems helpful for svn addiction.